# Image processing 1 bit images

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the basics for image processing an image of a corridor. I have have used PIL to convert find the edges in an image, then I have converted it to a 1 bit image. I know what I want to be able to extract - the longest horizontal and diagonal lines that can be found in the image. Any ideas?

```
from PIL import *
import Image, ImageFilter
im = im.open("c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PIL\corridor.jpg")
imageInfo=list(im.getdata())
im.putdata(imageInfo)
print pic.size
for i in imageInfo2[180:220]:
 if i==0:
    print "This is a BLACK pixel"
       elif i==255:
          print "This is a WHITE pixel"
       else:
         print "ERROR"
```

Answer (score 1):

First don't call them 1 bit images - that normally refers to images (like icons) where each pixel is 1bit and so 8pixels can be packed into a single byte.

Images with only two levels are normally called 'binary' in image processing.

Now you only have to learn the science of image processing !

A good place to start is [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) a free image processing library that also works with python and interfaces reasonably well with PIL.

You shoudl also read their book - or one of the other [good books on image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207092/image-processing-textbook)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, but i was hoping for a snippet of some self explanatory code as i have lots of books on digital process but they are all in java and other languages..i cant seem to find a good python book that explains the topic, any recommendations?

Comment: Most image processing books will be in C, but the algorithms are what matters. For finding lines you normally use something called a Hough transform - you don't need to know how to code it, jsut how to call a library containing it.  Check the documentation for PIL, scipy or opencv.  This is a complicated mathematical field - even if you are just using somebody elses lib